# Generate Objective-C code from any other language

Tags: objective-c

Are there frameworks/generators for producing iOS code from *any other language*?

A dynamic language like JavaScript, ruby or Python are preferred.  Googling for iOS code generators was largely fruitless.

The problem with systems like PhoneGap is that their output is a full-fledged application. What I need to produce is a library (.a & .h file eventually) that other Objective-C developers can reuse in their projects.

Comment: Objective-C is not a "pretty bad" language, you need to learn it and (maybe love it) otherwise you need to go with another framework such as [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch).

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I'm familiar with systems that allow app development without developing in Objective-C, but what I'm looking for is a way to produce Objective-C code from some other source.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a legitimate question.  Having used it, Obj-C is awful compared to the other languages out there.

Comment: Thanks @ThinkingSites, nonetheless I just reworded it to avoid the downvotes :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/) may or may not do what you want. I haven't seen much about the practicalities of it yet, but I'm thinking since it's statically compiled chances are good that it can produce libraries that can be simply linked into Objective-C projects. One might need another tool to produce the header files.

Of course, this is all speculation.

Comment: Thanks!  This is the closest thing suggested so far.  I'm looking into it now.

Comment: After researching RubyMotion, I found a post on the mailing list which indicates that my use case (creating a library) is not supported.  https://groups.google.com/group/rubymotion/browse_thread/thread/dafd1c4fbe05301/ad4e56df1691ea8c

Comment: Accepted because it's the closest to what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for what you're looking for is [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk). It has its own sdk (in JavaScript), a complete IDE and allows you to have one codebase for all major platforms (iOS, Android included). What it's really awesome is the fact that it actually generates native code (a valid XCode project or a Java one for Android). It's also free and open source. Definetely worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Alladinian.  I watched a tutorial and trolled through the forums.  Looks like it's more for handling the high level stuff (like tabbed views) and less for mucking with low-level libraries.  I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen code generators, but there are a variety of "spoofs" as it were.

http://xamarin.com/monotouch  - iOS on C#

http://phonegap.com/ - iOS on HTML, CSS , Javascript

http://ipodtoucher55.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-create-iphone-apps-in-flash-cs5.html - one of several tutorials for flash on iOS

I've seen links to python libraries and I think java too.

When it comes down to it though, they're all work arounds, not direct development.

Comment: Right, right.  My goal, sadly, is to produce Objective-C code.

Comment: Why?  If you can accomplish the same with other languages, why rely on Obj-C?

Comment: The output of the other systems is a full-fledged application.  What I need to produce is a library (.a & .h file eventually) that other Objective-C developers can reuse in their projects.  I'll add this to the question description.

Comment: Yes, that's important.  Sorry I can't be of help on that end.